# Would with if clause?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I would take this medicine if it would cure my illness .

I would take this medicine if it cured my illness.

I think both are correct but do they have the same meaning ? I think the most idiomatic is the second one

Comment: Your first example is fine. The second one requires preterite "cured", not "cures". Compare "I **will**  take this medicine if it **cures** my illness."

Comment: Why would is possible with if clause . Is  it because the future of I would take this medicine isI would cure my illness, I would take this medicine right now if it would cure my illness in 2 days

Comment: Same meaning, both remote conditionals. Just two slightly different ways of saying the same thing. Yes the second one is probably more common.

Comment: It's normal to match the the tense in the apodosis with that in the protasis (_if_ phrase).

Comment: Note: "I **will** take this medicine if it **cures** my illness" (open conditional, present tense).  / "I **would** take this medicine if it **cured** my illness" (remote conditional, preterite tense).

Comment: The second is vaguer about the temporal relationship. "I would pay the doctor if he cured my illness" suggests paying after the cure, but "I would take this medicine if it cured my illness" suggests taking before the cure. Sometimes there may be ambiguity.

Comment: if I knew now it would cure my illness first  then I would take  so the cure first ,

Comment: would/would is a one of my pet peeves mistake.

Answer (score -2):

> *I would take this medicine if it would cure my illness .*
>
> *I would take this medicine if it cured my illness.*

There's little semantic difference between the two; they are essentially just two similar ways to say the same thing.

The preterite (past tense) verb "would" marks them as being remote conditionals, the type where the condition is presented as a relatively remote possibility.

They contrast with the present tense forms of an open conditional, the type where the condition is neutral as to whether the condition will be met:

> *I will take this medicine if it cures my illness.*

Comment: "I will take this medicine if it will cure my illness. 
"I will take this medicine if it  cures my illness.   The difference  between these two is in certainty. The second one using present is more an affirmation that this medicine can  really cure this illness  where as  in the first it may not cure this illness. Am I right here